# Unable to push Nuget symbol package to CodeArtifact

Tags: continuous-integration, nuget, github-actions, dotnet-cli, aws-codeartifact

I'm new to CI pipelines but I didn't find any proper solution for this one. I'm building my solution to generate Nuget and Nuget symbol packages and push them to AWS CodeArtifact but it looks like every time the git action runner tries to push the symbol package (MyPackage.symbols.nupkg and MyPackage.snupkg I tried both formats) and gets success and then tries to push the nuget package (MyPackage.nupkg) and a 409 conflict error appears. When I try to check the CodeArtifact source, it shows every time Mypackage.nupkg but never the symbol package.

I've tried all these commands separately-

dotnet nuget push Mypackage.symbols.nupkg

dotnet nuget push Mypackage.snupkg

I'm using dotnet 6.

Comment: I got confirmation from AWS support that AWS CodeArtifact doesn't support NutGet symbol packages. In future, they may release an update for this. As a workaround, I'm pushing my packages to S3 bucket.

Comment: I have the same issue.  AWS should be ashamed. Symbols are core to debugging and with all of the other fanciness they have, this miss is a big one...